# Does expected value of F(x)/x(1-F(x)) have a name, F(x) is CDF? Is it related to hazard function?

Tags: limit, probability, cdf, expectations, hazard

I was solving a problem and encountered the following:

\sum (f(x)/x) (F(x)/(1-F(x))

Here f(x) is pmf and F(x) is CDF. Is expected value of F(x)/x(1-F(x)) a known function? I found out that f(x)/(1-F(x)) is called hazard function. Also, x is defined over positive values. It can be assumed that x is bounded between two values Xmin and Xmax.

I want to know more about characteristics of this expected value, is it bounded if we take sum until F(x) < 1?

I would appreciate if someone could help me understand this better.

Comment: Hmm, great question, but more suitable for stats.stackexchange.com. I don't recognize that expression, although I see it might blow up as F(x) approaches 1 and it's undefined for x > Xmax (since then F(x) = 1). I guess the product f(x) F(x)/(1 - F(x)) will remain bounded if f(x) decreases "fast enough" -- something you can investigate. Good luck and have fun.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it obviously should have been migrated to CrossValidated back when it first appeared but failing that it's just not about coding.